# brl-cad won't start - no version information available

Tags: cad

I tried to install brl-cad. When I now try to open archer (part of it), I get the message "unexpected error occurred" and start up doesn't finish. When I start the program from console, I get these:

```
user@user-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC:~$ archer

/usr/brlcad/bin/../bin/bwish: /usr/brlcad/lib/libpng16.so.16: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6)
ogl_configureWin_guts: Can't open font '9x15' or '-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-m-60-iso8859-1'

ogl_configureWin_guts: Can't open font '9x15' or '-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-m-60-iso8859-1'

ogl_configureWin_guts: Can't open font '9x15' or '-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-m-60-iso8859-1'

ogl_configureWin_guts: Can't open font '9x15' or '-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-m-60-iso8859-1'

ogl_configureWin_guts: Can't open font '9x15' or '-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-m-60-iso8859-1'
```

Does somebody have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: How did you install brl-cad? I would recommend downloading the source and building it on your machine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed it like recomanded here: http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-brl-cad-24-2-0-on-ubuntu-debian-fedora-opensuse-and-derivative-systems/

Comment: There is a slightly newer release available (7.26.4), but it may or may not fix your problem. If you download and install from source, it should configure to use your installed libpng. The BRL-CAD home page is: https://brlcad.org/

Comment: I installed it now from source, like you said. Like this https://brlcad.org/wiki/Compiling. The no information avaiable thing now disapeared. But I still got the other problem. Does I have to install adobe font styles? And if yes how can I do it. Searched this forum, but couldn`t find anithing suitable.  dm-X: Can't open font '9x15' or '-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-m-60-iso8859-1'v

Comment: You may need to install the gsfonts-x11 package to get the adobe fonts

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to edit the FONTBACK define in include/dm.h to specify a font you have enabled, or you'll need to enable one of the two fonts specified. Ubuntu apparently does not enable the old fixed pcf fonts, but it's supposedly easy:  http://marklodato.github.io/2014/02/23/fixed-fonts.html

You can similarly install the adobe fonts via gsfonts-x11 or package, and it should work.  Related: https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/couldnt-find-font-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-10-iso8859-1/21619/2

Comment: You could improve your answer by summarizing the steps to enable these fonts. A link is only useful until the content linked to changes.

Comment: I followed the instructions in root-forum. Now it works fine. Thanks to everybody who helped me.